# what is the difference between hosts file and nginx configure file?

Tags: nginx, hosts

if I have an entry in my hosts file ,and also the hostname is in the server block of the nginx configure file ,I wonder which file is applied first and does what specific,could someone tell me ?

Answer (score 2):

The hosts file is used by your OS to resolve hostnames to IPs and is usually evaluated first (can be customized - at least on unix based OS). If you tell an application to look for some host, e.g. www.example.com, it looks up the name in the hosts file and uses the IP to connect to that host. In case the hostname can't be found in the file, it will usually ask the configured DNS servers for it.. See [Hosts File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) for more info.

The hostname in the server block on the other side is used by nginx to determine the appropriate action to be taken. nginx evaluates the HOST header in the request and tries to match it against the values configured in the `server_name` variables in each block. See [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) and [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).